# partition ssd + hdd disk on ubuntu server running plesk

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, performance, hard-drive, plesk

i have a new server with `256 SSD` and `4TB SATA HDD`, with the following logical volumes mounted

```
# lsblk

NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1 223.4G  0 disk
├─sda1         8:1    1     4G  0 part /
├─sda2         8:2    1     2G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3         8:3    1 217.4G  0 part
  ├─ssd-usr  253:0    0     5G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─ssd-var  253:2    0     5G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─ssd-home 253:3    0     5G  0 lvm  /home
  └─ssd-opt  253:4    0     5G  0 lvm  /opt
sdb            8:16   1   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1         8:17   1   3.7T  0 part
  └─hdd-data 253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  /data
```

I'm going to expand the logical volumes to take the full space on both disks.

at the moment `/var` contains all the files for Websites, Databases,Mails and Backups and it resides  on the SSD which does not have a lot of space, on the other hand `/data` resides on the HDD and it is empty.

Which folders should i mount on the HDD disk and not sacrifice a lot of performance?

Comment: But you have nearly 200GB of unused space on your SSD!

Comment: Yes, as i said i am going to expand the logical volumes to take all the free space, but first i need to know what can i move to the HDD disk without losing performance